# Element-wise multiplication for sparse matrices in python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I was wondering if there is a operator for element-wise multiplication of rows of a sparse matrix with a vector in scipy.sparse library. Something similar to A*b for numpy arrays? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`multiply`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.multiply.html) method:

```
In [15]: a
Out[15]: 
<3x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [16]: a.A
Out[16]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 4, 5]])

In [17]: x
Out[17]: array([ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25])

In [18]: a.multiply(x)
Out[18]: 
matrix([[  5,   0,   0,  40,   0],
        [  0,   0,  45,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0,  80, 125]])
```

Note that the result is not a sparse matrix if `x` is a regular numpy array (`ndarray`).  Convert `x` to a sparse matrix first to get a sparse result:

```
In [32]: xs = csr_matrix(x)

In [33]: y = a.multiply(xs)

In [34]: y
Out[34]: 
<3x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [35]: y.A
Out[35]: 
array([[  5,   0,   0,  40,   0],
       [  0,   0,  45,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,  80, 125]])
```

Comment: `a.A` does not change `a`.  I only put that there to display the values in the array.  You can ignore it.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to get a sparse matrix result.